# In WinRT we have ListView and GridView - how about a simple list with columns and details (like Explorer details view)

Tags: windows, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I just want to create a list with data and columns (sortable).  I don't want tiles, I don't want right scrolling.  I just want a list like the "Listview" Win32 common control.  Or am I forced into the tile metaphor.

Comment: Don't force non-touch friendly UI into WinRT apps.  Read the Modern UI guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe they are not at a metaphor but from my point ListView in Win32 is one.

ListView in Win32 is a very limited control, unflexible and too ugly.

ListView and GridView xaml controls are far better aproach, I know.. switch from old style controls to new style is easy if you come from scratch but if you have old style background... is hard... I know.

If your lvw32 grows vertically based on data use a Listview (xaml) in wich each item is a Row and use the item template to put in a gridview,the gridview will be one register with all attributes (columns).

So your ListView will have a collection of Rows, each Row is a GridView who is a Collection of attributes.

This is a way, but you have a lot of different options.